# Access viewModel inside a service in android

Tags: android, mvvm, service, viewmodel, repository-pattern

how we can initialize the **viewModel** in a **service**.
in a fragment, we do that with Kotlin delegate "**by activityViewModels**".
or we can do it with the **ViewModelProvider().get**.
but as far as I find out we can not do it in service because we need a "**ViewModelStoreOwner**" like activity or fragment.

so is that even a best practice to initialize a ViewModel in a service?

[my project here](https://github.com/imansdn/SimpleFourSquare).

Comment: "because I need to call the repository class from my service" -- you do not need a viewmodel to do that.

Comment: @CommonsWare yeah you're right

Answer (score 17):

It is not recommended using a ViewModel in a service. You could call your repository from your service itself.

https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/issues/137#issuecomment-327854042

> The ViewModel should be used closely with an Activity or a Fragment,
> so it's destined to live in the UI layer of your application.
> Therefore, I don't recommend using the ViewModel in a Service. Create
> a different class, that would be used in the Service and, if needed,
> in the ViewModel. Like this you ensure the separation of concerns and
> avoid giving the ViewModel more responsibilities than needed.

Comment: In one single way viewModel should be in the service - dwaing overlay. In this case ussually is used foreground service + ui + viewModel + repositories AND developer repeat MVVM/MVI pattern inside the service

Answer (score 5):

define a base service, then you can using ViewModel like activity/fragment

```
public class LifecycleAndViewStoreOwnerService extends LifecycleService implements ViewModelStoreOwner, HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory {

    final ViewModelStore mViewModelStore = new ViewModelStore();
    ViewModelProvider.Factory mFactory;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewModelStore getViewModelStore() {
        return mViewModelStore;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        getLifecycle().addObserver(new LifecycleEventObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull LifecycleOwner source, @NonNull Lifecycle.Event event) {
                if (source.getLifecycle().getCurrentState() == Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED) {
                    mViewModelStore.clear();
                    source.getLifecycle().removeObserver(this);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewModelProvider.Factory getDefaultViewModelProviderFactory() {
        return mFactory != null ? mFactory : (mFactory = new ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(getApplication()));
    }
}
```

extend the above class, show an overlay window in service

```
public class MyLifecycleService extends LifecycleAndViewStoreOwnerService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyLifecycleService";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        final OverlayWindowBinding binding = OverlayWindowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(this));
        binding.setViewModel(new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ViewModel.class));
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        getSystemService(WindowManager.class).addView(binding.getRoot(), layoutParams);

        getLifecycle().addObserver(new LifecycleEventObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull LifecycleOwner source, @NonNull Lifecycle.Event event) {
                if (source.getLifecycle().getCurrentState() == Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED) {
                    getSystemService(WindowManager.class).removeViewImmediate(binding.getRoot());
                    source.getLifecycle().removeObserver(this);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static class ViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
        public ViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
            super(application);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll allow myself to insert my five cents: I use jetpack compose for overlay drawing from foreground service + hilt (yeah, it's a modern way). So, I hoped that `hiltViewModel`-compose would work, but it didn't ;) In the result I became to create a viewModel manually, like activityViewModel. This is an example of my vision, possible somebody will find it helpful:

```kotlin
abstract class AdvancedLifecycleService : LifecycleService(), SavedStateRegistryOwner, ViewModelStoreOwner {
  protected abstract val savedStateRegistryController: SavedStateRegistryController
    
  override val savedStateRegistry: SavedStateRegistry
    get() = savedStateRegistryController.savedStateRegistry
    
  override val viewModelStore: ViewModelStore = ViewModelStore()
    
  @Inject
  lateinit var overlayViewModelProvider: Provider<OverlayViewModel>
    
  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    savedStateRegistryController.performRestore(null)
    lifecycle.addObserver(object : LifecycleEventObserver {
      override fun onStateChanged(source: LifecycleOwner, event: Lifecycle.Event) {
        if (source.lifecycle.currentState == Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED) {
          viewModelStore.clear()
          source.lifecycle.removeObserver(this)
        }
      }
    })
    
    val a = ViewModelProvider(
      store = viewModelStore,
      factory = ForegroundViewModelFactory(
        overlayViewModelProvider = overlayViewModelProvider,
      ),
      defaultCreationExtras = CreationExtras.Empty
    )[OverlayViewModel::class.java]
    val b = ViewModelProvider(
      store = viewModelStore,
      factory = ForegroundViewModelFactory(
       overlayViewModelProvider = overlayViewModelProvider,
     ),
     defaultCreationExtras = CreationExtras.Empty
   )[OverlayViewModel::class.java]
   println("a == b: ${a == b}") // true
 }
    
 private class ForegroundViewModelFactory(
 private val overlayViewModelProvider: Provider<OverlayViewModel>,) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
  override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
    if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(OverlayViewModel::class.java)) {
      return overlayViewModelProvider.get() as T
    } else {
      throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
  }
}
}
```